# Unsuitable Screen Resolution

Tags: display, resolution

I've just installed eOS.  The initial screen resolution is a lot lower than the optimum for my screen.  The system doesn't seem to recognise the screen mark and model, and I can't find a means to do that within the System Settings.  So, how should I do that?  What should I read?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Hosam Adeeb Nashed

```
lspci:

00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 18)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 18)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset HECI Controller (rev 06)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB Universal Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1a.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB Universal Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1a.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB Universal Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1a.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio (rev 06)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 06)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev 06)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB Universal Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB Universal Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB Universal Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev a6)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation H55 Chipset LPC Interface Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 4 port SATA IDE Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset SMBus Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.5 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 2 port SATA IDE Controller (rev 06)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 06)
03:01.0 Multimedia audio controller: Creative Labs EMU10k1 [Sound Blaster Live! Series] (rev 08)
03:01.1 Input device controller: Creative Labs SB Live! Game Port (rev 08)
03:02.0 Multimedia video controller: Brooktree Corporation Bt878 Video Capture (rev 11)
03:02.1 Multimedia controller: Brooktree Corporation Bt878 Audio Capture (rev 11)
3f:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-core Registers (rev 05)
3f:00.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture System Address Decoder (rev 05)
3f:02.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Link 0 (rev 05)
3f:02.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 1st Generation Core i3/5/7 Processor QPI Physical 0 (rev 05)
3f:02.2 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 1st Generation Core i3/5/7 Processor Reserved (rev 05)
3f:02.3 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 1st Generation Core i3/5/7 Processor Reserved (rev 05)
```

Comment: Could you add more information about your hardware? Also, if you go to appcenter, do you see any drivers on the installed tab? You can try to install them if available.

Comment: The monitor is Dell 1910HC, the VGA is built into the motherboard, maybe Intel chip.  The default resolution is 1024x768, but the monitor's optimal resolution is 1440x900, which doesn't show on the list of available options.

Comment: It says [here](https://www1.la.dell.com/hn/en/corp/peripherals/monitor-dell-e1910h/pd.aspx?refid=monitor-dell-e1910h&s=corp) the maximum resolution is 1366x768. If you go to system settings do you have an option to set this resolution?

Comment: As a matter of fact, when the monitor is not connected it displays a message stating that its native resolution is what I had mentioned.  Besides, it did function in that resolution on another machine (Linux as well).  Apart from that, the settings do not offer any resolutions above 1024x768.

Comment: Please open a terminal and post the output of `lspci`. And just to be clear, did you install elementary 6 Odin  (the current version) ?

Comment: I will do as required shortly.  And yes, I had downloaded the most recent version, Odin.

Comment: 00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 18)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 18)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset HECI Controller (rev 06)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB Universal Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1a.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB Universal Host Controller (rev 06)

Comment: 00:1a.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB Universal Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1a.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio (rev 06)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 06)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev 06)

Comment: 00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB Universal Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB Universal Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB Universal Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev a6)

Comment: 00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation H55 Chipset LPC Interface Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 4 port SATA IDE Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset SMBus Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.5 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 2 port SATA IDE Controller (rev 06)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 06)

Comment: 03:01.0 Multimedia audio controller: Creative Labs EMU10k1 [Sound Blaster Live! Series] (rev 08)
03:01.1 Input device controller: Creative Labs SB Live! Game Port (rev 08)
03:02.0 Multimedia video controller: Brooktree Corporation Bt878 Video Capture (rev 11)
03:02.1 Multimedia controller: Brooktree Corporation Bt878 Audio Capture (rev 11)
3f:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-core Registers (rev 05)

Comment: 3f:00.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture System Address Decoder (rev 05)
3f:02.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Link 0 (rev 05)
3f:02.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 1st Generation Core i3/5/7 Processor QPI Physical 0 (rev 05)
3f:02.2 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 1st Generation Core i3/5/7 Processor Reserved (rev 05)
3f:02.3 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 1st Generation Core i3/5/7 Processor Reserved (rev 05)

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't paste the whole bulk in one go...

Comment: Don't worry. Next time remember you can edit the question to add that info. Since you have a processor from 2011 I believe it should have great support by default. Maybe we can try the following https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/i7sgtm/how_to_install_intel_hd_graphics_drivers/g13spes/

Comment: Thank you a whole lot for your efforts with me!!
I did as described in that link, but to no avail, I'm afraid.